# What race are Guido and Nunzio?

Tags: myth-adventures

I was recently helping to answer a question where someone was seeking out the *[Myth-Adventures](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/MythAdventures)* series by Robert Asprin. I was describing several characters and where they come from and I came to Guido and Nunzio. If I recall correctly, they're first encountered on Deva. Their boss, Don Bruce, is a literal Fairy Godfather. So, what are Guido and Nunzio? Straight humans? Humanoids like the Trollops (and, arguably, Klahds)? Which dimension do they originate from?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Also specifically addressed by Guido when he's blackmailing Frumple in *MYTH Inc. in Action*.  When Frumple threatens to turn the tables on him and Nunzio and reports them for demons if they turn him in Guido says... err sez

> 'While I will admit that my cousin and me have done some dimension travellin', this particular dimension of Klah happens to be our home territory'.

So from the horse's mouth... they're Klahds.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think it is ever addressed specifically in the books.  I think I assumed that they were Klahds (which are the closest to real-world humans in the series, basically).  The mafia organization they were part of was certainly active on Klah; Big Julie's whole army owed the mob money.  That's hardly definitive, but it suggested to me that the main body of mafiosi and criminal associates were from Klah.

Comment: I finally got around to reading the text in *Hit or Myth* and yeah, they're local boys, Shai-ster's bodyguards on Klah, and the Mob was unaware of Deva, which suggests they don't really get off-dimension.